# Mapping to denormalized properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've got a pair of database tables that looks like:

```
Task
- Id : int (PK)
- AccountId : int (FK)

TaskStartInterval
- TaskId : int (PK, FK)
- Index : int (PK)
- AccountId: int (FK)
- StartDateTime : datetime2(0)
- EndDateTime : datetime2(0)
```

There a one-to-many relationship between these tables (`Task.Id > TaskStartInterval.TaskId`).

You'll also notice I've denormalized the `AccountId` property - this is stored against the `TaskStartInterval` as well as the `Task` to support queries based on an `AccountId` & `DateTime`. As you'd imagine, the `AccountId` of a `TaskStartInterval` is always the same as that of the related Task.

How can I model this denormalized property in Entity Framework? Ideally I'd want to hide the property from `TaskStartInterval` altogether, but have the intelligence in there such that it looks at the related `Task` for the property value. Is this possible?

Comment: can you include `AccountId` in the PK of `Task` ?

Comment: I could, but Task already has an identity field (Id) so it doesn't particularly need to include the AccountId. I can see how it'd work in my favour, but it feels more like a workaround. I'm sure there must be something in EF which can handle this, I just haven't been able to figure out what.